# ¿Cómo recorro un objeto de arreglos a formato JSON en PHP?

Tags: php, array

> necesito que $response de como resultado esto: [1,2,3,4,5] PERO OBTENGO ESTO:[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

```
 public function getNotificacionAdmin()
    {
        $response = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from notificacion where id_tipo = 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $response[] = array(
                $row['id_dispositivo']
            );

        }
        return $response;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba modificar como se van agregando los elementos al array y como se inicializa el arreglo. 
En tu codigo defines el siguiente bucle

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $response[] = array(
            $row['id_dispositivo']
        );

    }
```

Lo modificaria por la siguiente forma

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $response[] =
            $row['id_dispositivo']
        ;

    }
```

Como puede verse, cuando itero, voy agregando en tu arreglo **$response** los *id* que vienen de tu consulta en el *$row[id_dispositivo]*.

Probalo y avisame si te sirve como soluciòn. Muchos exitos

Comment: Gracias, funcionó

Comment: Buenisimo! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Solo quita el array()

```
public function getNotificacionAdmin()
    {
        $response = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from notificacion where id_tipo = 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $response[] = $row['id_dispositivo'];

        }
        return $response;

    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no me había fijado en ese pequeño detalle

Comment: Si te resolvió, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada, gracias